# How to merge 2 project into 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have downloaded a calendar project for iphone from internet, and now I want to add this calendar project/code in my project. My project is for ipad and tab based project in which on pressing first tab calendar should be display.

Please guide me how I add calendar project/code in my project/code.

Comment: Maybe it'd help us if you told us exactly _what_ did you download from _where._ It'd be more helpful though if you explained in an answer how you solved your problem however.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the classes, resources such as images from that project to your project and use the class appropriately. If there are any frameworks or libraries used, you should link them too. I don't think there is any option for direct merging.

Comment: Actually I m getting error only on including calendar file in my project not even I have change any code...

Comment: sending the whole project will take time for you. What is the error you are getting, may be that can help me to know, where you are going wrong.